# Some strings are being displayed outside the <a> tag?

Tags: jquery, html

So I am making a jquery plugin that gets some headlines which is working fine, but when I try and output the results on to an HTML page some of the headlines are being displayed outside the  tag they are supposed to be inside?

HTML:

```
<div class="news"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(el).append('<li class=' + options.listClassName + '>' + '<a href=' + link[1] + '>' + e.title + '</a></li>')
```

And when I load the webpage here is how it is displayed when I 'Inspect element'

```
<div class="news">
    <li class="item">
        <a href="http://example.com/link/to/article.html"></a>Article Headline
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <a href="http://example.com/link/to/article.html">Article Headline</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <a href="http://example.com/link/to/article.html">Article Headline</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <a href="http://example.com/link/to/article.html">Article Headline</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <a href="http://example.com/link/to/article.html">Article Headline</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <a href="http://example.com/link/to/article.html"></a>Article Headline
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <a href="http://example.com/link/to/article.html">Article Headline</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <a href="http://example.com/link/to/article.html"></a>Article Headline
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <a href="http://example.com/link/to/article.html"></a>Article Headline
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <a href="http://example.com/link/to/article.html">Article Headline</a>
    </li>
</div>
```

As you can see some of the headlines are not inside the  tag whilst some are?

Any help would be much obliged!

Regards,
Ben

Comment: _li's are supposed to be inside_ `UL` not inside `div`

Comment: or `<menu>` in HTML5 (still not supported)

Comment: I changed it to `ul` but it made no difference

Comment: We were just being picky (; , can you put your code in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so it's easier to debug, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div><ul class="news"></ul></div>

$('.news').append('<li class=\"' + options.listClassName + '\">' + '<a href=\"' + link[1] + '\">' + e.title + '</a></li>')
```

See `\"` added.

Comment: Wow, that worked thanks! (I didn't need the enclosing div though),

Comment: While I agree that adding quotes around attribute values is a good thing, how could this cause the OP's problem? I mean, only a problem for some of the items? Wouldn't it have been an all-or-nothing thing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know reason why your getting wrong output but i prefer to define my html with dynamic jquery

```
$(el).append($('<li>')
.addClass(options.listClassName)
.append($('<a>')
    .attr('href', link[1])
    .text(e.title)
    )
);
```

Example JsFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/utku/ZvVtv/

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var li=$('<li />').addClass(options.listClassName);
var a=$('<a />').attr('href',link[1]).text(e.title);
li.append(a);
$(el).append(li);
```

And also change the div to ul, like pXL says.